# How to specify xsi:type for an element in SOAP request using node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, exacttarget

I'm trying to call the `Create` method passing in a `TriggeredSend` typed object named `Objects` to an ExactTarget SOAP Web Service using the node-soap package.

I need to create something that looked like this (note the `xsi:type="ns0:TriggeredSend"`):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:etns="http://exacttarget.com" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:CreateRequest>
         <ns0:Objects xsi:type="ns0:TriggeredSend">
            <ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
               <ns0:CustomerKey>abc</ns0:CustomerKey>
            </ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
         </ns0:Objects>
      </ns0:CreateRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

With the code below I get close:

```
var soap = require('soap')

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    client.Create({
        Objects: {
            TriggeredSendDefinition: {
                CustomerKey: 'abc'
            }
        },
        function(err, response) {})
    });
});
```

Which gives me this (without the `xsi:type`):

```
<ns0:CreateRequest>
   <ns0:Objects>
     <ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
        <ns0:CustomerKey>abc</ns0:CustomerKey>
     </ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
  </ns0:Objects>
</ns0:CreateRequest>
```

How do I specify the `TriggeredSend` type for the `Objects` element?

Answer (score 5):

There is a special `attributes` node you can add to specify the `xsi:type`:

```
var soap = require('soap')

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    client.Create({
        Objects: {
            attributes: {
                xsi_type: {
                    type: 'TriggeredSend',
                    xmlns: 'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI'
                }
            }
            TriggeredSendDefinition: {
                CustomerKey: 'abc'
            }
        },
        function(err, response) {})
    });
});
```

Which produces:

```
<ns0:CreateRequest>
   <ns0:Objects xsi:type="ns0:TriggeredSend">
      <ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
         <ns0:CustomerKey>abc</ns0:CustomerKey>
      </ns0:TriggeredSendDefinition>
   </ns0:Objects>
</ns0:CreateRequest>
```